# How to make correct regex for matching content from html?

Tags: python, regex

I use regexr for making regular expression, but can't matching anything.

I wrote such regex **'.dataLayer = (.+)</script>'**

I have such structure of template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-PH" dir="ltr"> 
<head> … </head> 
<body class="is_full PdpV4"> 
<script> This one script which I should get </script>
 <script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; dataLayer.push({"feature_test":"VariableControl:1"}); dataLayer.push({"feature_set":"Control"}); 
</script> 
<script>....</script> 
<script> … </script>
 </body> 
</html>
```

And I need to get the first one script... /script

```
<script>
    dataLayer = [
        {
            "agent_id": 558921,
            "agent_name": "The City Townhouse",
            "attributes": {
                "agent_ratings_enabled": 0,
                "approved": 1,
                                "attribute_set_id": 1,
                                "categories": JSON.parse("[15,19]"),
                "indoor_features": ["Balcony","Maid's room"],
                "is_agent": 1,
                "listing_type": "Classifieds",
                "other_features": [],
                "outdoor_features": ["Garage"],
                "price_formatted": "₱ 11,300,000 ",
                "price_not_shown": false,
                "seller_is_trusted": 1,
                "show_listing_address": 1,
                "show_mobile": 1
        }
    ];
</script>
```

I need to get everything inside tags  . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there anything else outside of the `<script>` tag? Or does your "template" string start and end like in your example, only having the `script` element?

Comment: There are several <script></script> in the body of the template.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-PH" dir="ltr">
<head> … </head>
<body class="is_full  PdpV4">
 <script> This one script which I should get </script>

 <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            dataLayer.push({"feature_test":"VariableControl:1"});
                        dataLayer.push({"feature_set":"Control"});
        </script>

 <script>....</script>

 <script> … </script>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: @try_to_code `/.dataLayer = (.+?)<\/script>/gs` regex. Add the s flag to regex.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add this to the input? Is it the very *first* script content you need? How do you decide which script is of your interest?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid parsing HTML with regular expressions. A [seminal stack overflow answer explains why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/39808).

Instead, you should use a package like [html5lib](https://html5lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/html5lib.html) to parse the HTML and extract the contents of the `<script>` elements and then parse out the contents you want from that. This will mean you only need to look at the JavaScript code, which should be a much simpler task.

Answer (score 0):

First, what Paul said, don't use a regex to parse HTML.

Second, and I don't recommend it, but if you're really intent on doing this for whatever reason, this regex will match characters on the inside of a `<script>..</script>` tag:

```
(?<=<script>).*(?=<\/script>)
```

You have been warned.